# Create task that builds cpp and c files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have task in my `task.json` file in Visual Studio Code that builds project :

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: build",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    },
```

Task is called from `launch.json`. Does line `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` means that task builds only `cpp` files? How to deal if project has both - `cpp` and `c` files?

Comment: Setup vs code for using cmake. For a couple of files use `"${workspaceFolder}/*.c*"`

Comment: With `"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` you will always get different output binaries depending on a currently open file. `"${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolder}"` may be a better choice.

Comment: `"${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolder}"` is not good, because you will get something like -o `/mnt/c/aaa//mnt/c/aaa`

Comment: `"${workspaceFolder}/*.c*"` is not good, because it includes `*.code-workspace file`

Answer (score 0):

G++ can compile any .c or .cpp files but they will be treated as C++ files only.
GCC can compile any .c or .cpp files but they will be treated as C and C++ respectively.

> compilerArgs (optional) Compiler arguments to modify the includes or defines used, for example -nostdinc++, -m32, etc.

You could try using GCC.

Else if you have a main.cpp the uses

```
#include "example.h"
#include "example2.h"
```

compiling only the main file should work.

Perhaps this might bring some more clarification : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Answer (score 0):

```json
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: build",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.c", // this should build c and cpp at the same time.
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
    },
```